# Intellij ctrl+alt+arrow hotkeys not working

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, intellij-idea

I can't make IntelliJ 14.1.4 act on the ctrl+alt+arrow hotkeys on Windows 7. 
I already disabled the Intel hotkeys and don't know any further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was the **Intel HD Graphics Control Panel Service**. The service does not release its hotkeys even after they are disabled. Disabling the service in msconfig.exe and restart solves the problem.

Comment: Strangely, for me just disabling the shortcuts seems to have helped immediately.

Answer (score 18):

I disabled the `Intel HD Graphics Control Panel Service` from loading at startup, **Restarted** and now it works fine.

[image]

Comment: You could also just disable the shortcuts in this graphics control panel, but yes, this service was definitely at fault.

Answer (score 10):

no need to disable IntelHDGraphics control panel (IHDGCP)

just disable shortcuts 
1) right click IHDGCP icon in the tray
2) graphics options
3) hot keys
4) disable

thats it.

Comment: According to the accepted answer this does not work "The service does not release its hotkeys even after they are disabled"

Comment: on my side it works, so i decided to add painless way to this old topic as an alternative.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I just tested it and the accepted answer is wrong. disabling hotkeys fix the issue instantly.

Comment: In my case i go to Intel Graphic Command Center > System > Hotkeys, turn on and turn off again ("The service does not release its hotkeys" so turn on and off solved the problem for me.)

Answer (score 4):

**Confirmed, on my machine disabling hotkeys did nothing.**

Sadly I had no administration privileges for disabling that service on my machine. Other solution that works, is to change the hotkey from the original one to something relevant.

Source: https://communities.intel.com/thread/51399

> Changing the hotkeys to something else will release the hotkeys so it
>   looks as though the driver registers the hotkeys no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

first, open `Intel Hd Graphics Control Panel` and go to `Options and Support`, then doing follow setting:

[image]

```
Manage Hot Keys: 
    Enable
  ✓ Disable
```

Answer (score 2):

This program should show you is something else is handling the Ctrl-Alt-Arrow combination currently: 
https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=18189.msg163170#top

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way of figuring our what program is handling it.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/threads/how-to-disable-screen-orientation-hotkeys-ctrl-alt-arrow.17069/

I found the solution here.

In Windows
CTL + ALT + F12 opens Intel control panel. Go to options and **disable hot keys**.

This is how it looks, but I added more details.
https://superuser.com/a/1198318/522926

If you need to enable hot keys back (note, CTL + ALT + F12 will not work), go to **Start menu in Windows** **paste Intel Graphics** and run one of these files:
Gfxv4_0.exe, GfxUIEx.exe, Gfxv2_0.exe.

Intel Graphics

Answer (score 0):

It is still the issue with Intel **Graphics Control Center** even with **disabled** state.

Best way to mitigate is to reassign the keys to Ctrl+Shift:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Lenovo users:

I had the same problem on my Lenovo X220 notebook (Windows 7).
The root cause was Lenovo application named:
Lenovo Screen Reading Optimizer.
This application also allocate CTRL+ALT+ARROWs combinations.
Just uninstall this app. It solved this problem in my case.